# A non-flat functor that reflects exact sequences

Tags: category-theory, examples-counterexamples, abelian-categories, flatness

A faithfully flat functor from an abelian category to another abelian category is an additive preserves and reflects (short) exact sequences. What is an example of a functor that reflects (short) exact sequences but does not preserve them? Also what is such a functor called? (A faithful functor means something else - injective on Hom sets.)

Comment: I assume you want your functors to be additive?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the question.

Comment: Do you want reflection of all exact sequences of any length, or just short exact sequences?

Comment: Short exact would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the direct sum of a functor that preserves and reflects exact sequences and a functor that is not exact.

For example, take the functor
$$F(A) = A\oplus\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},A)$$
from abelian groups to abelian groups.